# Number of rows of a gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview, rows

I'm trying to make a gridview that has only two rows.
My intention is to make it look like a gallery with two rows, one above the other and with a horizontal scroll.
I see that you can change the number of columns in the gridview, but can not find how to change the number of rows.
I appreciate any help, and if not possible using with gridview also appreciate any ideas.

Comment: The number of rows is automatically calculated(and imposed by you) from the number of columns and the number of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RecycleView instead of GridView.

With RecyclerView you can make Horizontal and Vertical Grid Like Views.

With GridLayoutManager, you can set horizontal recyclerview with limited number of rows.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html

Refer this method in documentation,

```
 GridLayoutManager (Context context, 
            int spanCount, 
            int orientation, 
            boolean reverseLayout)
```

Answer (score 0):

yes,its possible to display fixed row of gridview with the help of fix height of your parent layout and also remove scrollview as parent GridView automatically maintaining scrollView.